# Doctrine DBAL - Transaction and inserts outside transaction

Tags: php, mysql, orm, mariadb, dbal

Hello I have service which works in transactions, it's communicating with remote API and I want to log every request/response in this API, but if main transaction rollback, any logs will be rollbacked too.

What I think is to clone DBAL connection. Will it open second connection with no transaction where I can insert with no fear of rollback ?

And is there any other way to work-around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your logging table a not respect the transactions by using a non-transactional storage engine such as MyISAM for that table only.

This is similar to an autonomous transaction in Oracle, and was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282779/django-mysql-how-to-do-autonomous-transactions-commit-only-sub-set-of-querie).

Comment: I was thinking of second connection, but I wonder if just clone $DBALObject will open second connection or keep reference to first one. I will have to try.

Comment: I just tried: clone $dbalConnection; DOES NOT open connection, it's reference. Here is my work-around:

`$secondDBAL = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($firstDbal->getParams());`